# Is there an easy way to track page link position in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, dom-events, adobe-analytics

I just want to be able to know if a user is clicking via the left nav, top nav, bottom nav, entry body, etc.  The equivalent functionality of [this Omniture plugin](http://webanalyticsland.com/sitecatalyst-implementation/track-hbx-style-links-in-sitecatalyst/).  I googled around but I must not be phrasing my Google searches correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "clickmap".  Anyways, GA doesn't have built-in tracking for this but you can imitate it easy enough with [event tracking](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html).

The overall principle is to trigger an event, passing some values, whenever a link is clicked. Since you are just wanting basic information (what area of the page user clicks on, divided in sections), you would essentially just do the following for all your links:

```
<a href="url" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'clickmap', 'left nav']);"some link</a>
```

'clickmap' would be the main category and would be the same value for all your links, and 'left nav' would be replaced with the designated area of the page.

You can of course hardcode it into all of your links but hopefully your html is coded well enough to be more programmatic about it, like for instance, use a framework like jQuery to dynamically append it to all the links in X area.